# Calculating degenerate states for N-dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to generalize a calculation of degenerate states,(from quantum mechanics n1^2 + n2^2 +n3^2 = Energy) but can't quite get the iteration down right. 
Creating a list of size N that starts with all zeroes. then want to slowly iterate each number of that list, sum together the squares of each number in that list, and check to see if they equal a given number. If not, increase number by one and check again.

```
 def sqsum(a):
      return sum(a[i]**2 for i in range(len(a)))
 def degeneracy(n,E):
      import numpy as np
       a=[0]*n #creates a list of zeroes of size n [0,0,0,....]
       z=0  #used to count number of degenerate states
       print(a, "original")
       EE=int(np.floor(np.sqrt(E)))

    for i in range(len(a)): #iterates through list a[]
        print(i)
        if a[i]<=EE:
            for j in a:
                sum=0
                print(a)
                sum+=a[j]*a[j] 
            if sum == E:
                print("sum equals", sum)
                z+=1
        a[i]+=1

    print("Total number of degenerate states is", z)
```

Problem is that I can get the first number in the list to iterate
[0,0,0],
[1,0,0],
[2,0,0] and so on, but I also want to iterate the other numbers, then have it reset after a point.
[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[2,0,0],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[0,1,0].
If someone could help me figure out the loop, that would be great.
*Edit(woops, realized the sqsum() function up top is part of other attempt at this, you can ignore it)